# How does Neo appear in the Matrix so soon after the ship got EMP'd?

Tags: the-matrix

The whole ship just got EMP'd and then the next scene shows Neo in the Matrix. Not sure how he got back in so quickly, or at all, since the ship shouldn't be working, right?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Just to be clear, are you referring to the scene near the end of the film, where Morpheus triggered the Nebuchadnezzar's EMP device to take out the Sentinels attacking the ship?

Comment: I'm not sure that the temporal sequence you are describing occurs anywhere in the 1999 movie.

Comment: @Buzz - They're referring to the very end of the film

Comment: Yea, the end, thank you.

Comment: I kind of figured some time (at least a day) passed between those scenes.

Comment: So you don't think the emp fried the ship? Made it unusable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can see in the shooting script, Neo escaped the Matrix just in the nick of time, *before* the EMP was triggered.

> 215 INT. HALL
>
> 215 Again he hears her. He reacts to the RINGING PHONE, rushing toward
> it even as —
>
> 216 INT. MAIN DECK A sentinel descends towards Morpheus. On the screen
> we see Neo dive for the phone as —
>
> Trinity: Now!
>
> Morpheus turns the key

After a bit of dialogue and some smooching, we then

> "fade to black"

which is [movie shorthand for the scene ending](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FadeToBlack). We come back ***an indeterminate amount of time later*** for the following scene with Neo talking on the phone before flying off like Mary Poppins.

Note also that we see the same hovership in the subsequent films, so it would appear that an EMP does not fatally disrupt their systems.

Answer (score -1):

I think the EMP doesn't affect devices which are turned off. So they just had to turn on whatever they used to connect to the Matrix when it was safe.

Comment: The Nebuchadnezzar's systems appeared to be switched on when Morpheus triggered the ship's EMP device near the end of the first film.

Comment: Electromagnetic radiation behaves like waves most of the time but sometimes acts like particles. In cases where EMP has no apparent effect, it’s because the hovercraft broke out some bullet-time king fu, dodging the EMP particles.

Comment: That must be it, the Nebuchadnezzar broke out some emp dodging kung fu lol